# Error retraining Inception using google cloud ml sample code

Tags: google-cloud-ml

When running in Cloud Shell the sample code from [this posting by Google's Slaven Bilac](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow), an error occurs.

```
chuck@wordone-wordtwo-1234567:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/flowers$ ./sample.sh
Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-270]


Using job id:  flowers_chuck_20170130_212715

# Takes about 30 mins to preprocess everything.  We serialize the two
# preprocess.py synchronous calls just for shell scripting ease; you could use
# --runner DataflowPipelineRunner to run them asynchronously.  Typically,
# the total worker time is higher when running on Cloud instead of your local
# machine due to increased network traffic and the use of more cost efficient
# CPU's.  Check progress here: https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow
python trainer/preprocess.py \
  --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
  --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
  --cloud
WARNING:root:Couldn't find python-snappy so the implementation of _TFRecordUtil._masked_crc32c is not as fast as it could be.
WARNING:root:BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner is deprecated, use BlockingDataflowRunner instead.
WARNING:root:BlockingDataflowRunner is deprecated, use DataflowRunner instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 446, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])

  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 442, in main
run(arg_dict)
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 361, in run
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
  File "/home/chuck/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 131, in __init__
    'Pipeline has validations errors: \n' + '\n'.join(errors))
ValueError: Pipeline has validations errors: 
Missing GCS path option: temp_location.
```

How can one modify the file(s) from [GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/flowers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers) to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the [CloudShell setup script](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up)?  It helps manage some of the versions, which seems to be the core issue here:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/master/tools/setup_cloud_shell.sh | bash
```

Comment: Yes, I did, without success.  Then, I created an entirely new Google Cloud account (with new billing account, new project, etc) and ran CloudShell setup script and the other steps to setup environment (from your link); but have same error with this account, too.  Thank you for responding, @JoshGC, do you have any other suggestion, please?

Comment: Workaround:  At line 420 in trainer/preprocess.py, add a temp_location key to the default_values dictionary:
'temp_location':
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(parsed_args.output_path), 'staging'),

Comment: When I used your workaround, I received no error for preprocess.py, thank you.  Unfortunately, there was an error after the trainer was built and successfully installed.  Immediately after "Start master session a0329944695ea674 with config:", there was an error associated with: device_filters: "/job:ps".  @ChrisMeyers, do you have any further suggestions, please?

Comment: I just pushed a new sample to github with a few fixes around changing versions.  I successfully ran the sample end to end on cloudshell.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you for your responsiveness. Especially on Super Bowl weekend. Marking this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Chuck,

it seems that the problem you are seeing is due to versioning mismatch.  Simple fix is to replace staging_location with temp_location in default_values dic inside preprocess.py:

```
default_values = {
    'project':
        get_cloud_project(),
    # **here**  
    'temp_location':
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(parsed_args.output_path), 'temp'),
    'runner':
        'DataflowRunner',
    'extra_package':
        Default.CML_PACKAGE,
    'save_main_session':
        True,
}
```

We will be updating the sample shortly to reflect this.

Comment: When I used your above workaround, I received the exact same error as before.  When I used your above workaround and also changed line 402 to   parser.add_argument(
      '--temp_location', type=str, help='Path to the staging location.'), I appears to work.  My job is waiting to start; once it finishes I will mark this questions answered, thank you.

Comment: The job failed.  The trainer was built and successfully installed.  But there was an error immediately after "Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222".  So I think my modification to your workaround was incorrect.  Slaven, do you have any suggestions?